# Class App\Admin\Selectable\ContactSelect must be a sub class of OpenAdmin\Admin\Grid\Selectable

Tags: php, laravel, subclass

I'm trying to use a relation based on documentation from Open Admin.
My Model Files :

```
App\Model\Contact.php

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contact';
}
```

```
App\Model\WorkObject.php

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class WorkObject extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'work_object';

    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class);
    }

}
```

```
App\Model\ConatctSelect.php

<?php

namespace App\Admin\Selectable;


use App\Models\Contact;
use OpenAdmin\Admin\Grid\Filter;
use OpenAdmin\Admin\Grid\Selectable;

class ContactSelect extends Selectable
{
    public $model = Contact::class;
    public static $display_field = "contact";

    public function make()
    {
        $this->column('Name');
        $this->column('company');
        $this->column('phone');
        $this->column('email');

        $this->filter(function (Filter $filter){
            $filter->like('name');
            //$filter->like('company');
            //$filter->like('phone');
            //$filter->like('email');
        });
    }
}
```

Controller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use App\Admin\Selectable\ContactSelect;
use App\Models\Contact;
use OpenAdmin\Admin\Controllers\AdminController;
use OpenAdmin\Admin\Form;
use OpenAdmin\Admin\Grid;
use OpenAdmin\Admin\Show;
use \App\Models\WorkObject;

class WorkObjectController extends AdminController

//------

protected function grid()
    {
        $grid = new Grid(new WorkObject());

       //
        $grid->column('contact_id', 'Osoba kontaktowa')->belongsTo(ContactSelect::class);
       //

        return $grid;
    }

//------

protected function form()
    {
        $form = new Form(new WorkObject());
       //
        $form->belongsTo('contact_id', ContactSelect::class, 'Osoba kontaktowa');
       //

        return $form;
    }
```

Im getting error of list and add new objetc

```
InvalidArgumentException In BelongsTo.php line 54 :
  [Class [App\Admin\Selectable\ContactSelect] must be a sub class of OpenAdmin\Admin\Grid\Selectable
```

Everything looks fine but the error keeps coming back. I have verified several times that the item is entered correctly and that there are no typos.

This is my first question here so forgive me for the confusion and maybe not professionally asked question.

The ContactSelect class is in namspace and has an extend Selectable. How to solve this bug. I am using Laravel v10.13.5 and Open Admin v1.0

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).